SFMC Push Notification to custom Web URL
I would like to send a push notification that uses the Journey Builder option, "Go to Web URL: Insert a URL in the field that goes to a web page."
Does this field support a content block or ampscropt so if I want to pass URL parameters with the URL in this space I am able to?
If not, Any suggestions on how I can send a push notification that opens a webpage that uses URL parameters to pre-fill an experience?

You can create a content block to build the URL logic and refer that Content block ID or path in the journey builder Push activity.
